# My 'ALT GR' button doesnt seem to be working properly on my VMware virtual machine

Tags: keyboard, vmware, keyboard-layout, kali-linux

So i just did a fresh install of Kali Linux on my virtual machine (VMware) - however it seems like my keyboard is not mapped correctly, atleast thats my theory, when i am using my host machine it works properly. I am not able to make "@" symble anywhere in the VM or any other combination with the 'ALT' button at all.

I am using a danish keyboard layout, and i am pretty sure i chose the right layout in the keyboard settings.
It's a pretty big deal for me to have the alt buttons so if anyone know how to fix this please share your solution with me :-)

Let me know if you need more information about the issue.